# Reading sas7bdat large file using modin panda: FactoryDispatcher.read_sas() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, modin

I want to read a large file in jupyter notebook. (can not read using pandas becuase of the memory constraints).
The datafile requres over 35 GB memory but my space has only 20 GB. Therefore, I tried to use modin panda instead but occured error.

FactoryDispatcher.read_sas() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

```
## Reading sas7bdat
import modin.pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

cabd_2021 = pd.read_sas(
  '/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxxx/xxx/xxxx_010121.sas7bdat',
   format = "sas7bdat",
    encoding="latin-1"
 )
cabd

Returns ERROR
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 3
      1 ## Les datafil fra SAS
----> 3 cabd= pd.read_sas()

File ~/jxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/modin/logging/logger_decorator.py:128, in enable_logging.<locals>.decorator.<locals>.run_and_log(*args, **kwargs)
    113 """
    114 Compute function with logging if Modin logging is enabled.
    115 
   (...)
    125 Any
    126 """
    127 if LogMode.get() == "disable":
--> 128     return obj(*args, **kwargs)
    130 logger = get_logger()
    131 logger_level = getattr(logger, log_level)

File ~/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/modin/pandas/io.py:581, in read_sas(filepath_or_buffer, format, index, encoding, chunksize, iterator, compression)
    577 Engine.subscribe(_update_engine)
    578 from modin.core.execution.dispatching.factories.dispatcher import FactoryDispatcher
    580 return DataFrame(
--> 581     query_compiler=FactoryDispatcher.read_sas(
    582         filepath_or_buffer,
    583         format=format,
    584         index=index,
    585         encoding=encoding,
    586         chunksize=chunksize,
    587         iterator=iterator,
    588         compression=compression,
    589     )
    590 )

TypeError: FactoryDispatcher.read_sas() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a [Modin bug](https://github.com/modin-project/modin/issues/5477) that was fixed in a [pull request](https://github.com/modin-project/modin/pull/5465) that has not made it into a release yet. You can [install the latest version of Modin](https://modin.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/installation.html#installing-from-the-github-master-branch) to get the fix, or you can wait for the next patch release of Modin. If you can't change your Modin version, you can read the dataframe into pandas with `pandas.read_sas`, then [construct](https://modin.readthedocs.io/en/stable/flow/modin/pandas/dataframe.html#usage-guide) a Modin dataframe out of the resulting pandas dataframe.